# error during sample data deployment

Tags: magento2, sample-data

i run `bin/magento sampledata:deploy` and get this error:

```
Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error
Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more info

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.



  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
  Your configuration does not allow connection to http://packagist.org. See h  
  ttps://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.             



require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-plugins] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [packages1] ... [packagesN]


There is an error during sample data deployment. Composer file will be reverted.
```

Any solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33501240/composer-error-while-installing-laravel-failed-to-decode-response-zlib-decode

Comment: @AnkitShah OK :)

Comment: Helpful? Works ?

Comment: it works @AnkitShah

Comment: Thanks. Moderators u can mark for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33501240/composer-error-while-installing-laravel-failed-to-decode-response-zlib-decode. That solved my issue :)